# Pixelated glass refractions with Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, glass

Is there a way to increase the refraction resolution in Eevee? Currently the lens refractions are very pixelated:

[image: Pixelated refractions]

[image: Pixelated refractions]

I have un-ticked the "Half Res Trace" under Screen Space Reflections and also tried to increase Cubemap Size and Filter Quality under Indirect Lighting in Render Settings, but they don't have any effect. Refractions remain ugly.